# Can a ratio variable be trend stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test

Can a ratio variable, e.g. the wage share of factor incomes, really be trend stationary? It is bounded between 0 and 1 and moves in between during long periods, acting like a non-stationary variable. Given this, unit root tests on it should be with a constant and no trend, right?
The same should be applied to other ratio variables, e.g. the debt-to-GDP ratio, in my opinion, since many such variables cannot increase infinitely. E.g. it is highly unlikely that debt may exceed GDP by a thousand or a million times.

Comment: Sure, consider the ratio of a Uniform(0,1) variable to 1 + a Poisson variate whose mean increases by 0.1 every period.   That doesn't mean that the specific examples you cite are trend stationary, and frankly I doubt the are.

Comment: There are ratios that are bounded between 0 and 1 and there are unbounded ones. When it comes to trend stationarity, I think they could be treated differently.

Comment: So your recommendation is that unit root tests for my ratio variables should be done without trends?